# shared perferences check value and redirect to next activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am having  splash screen in that i have declared two shared preferences String (controller_sim,master_sim)..................i check their  values present hai ki nai agar nai hai to unitno activity par redirect kar aur agar values present hai to menu activity par rerdirect kar.............and call meagar kuch samja nai toh................

aur ek bar set kar di values unit no se toh vo hamesha menu class mai redirect hona cahiye

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
public static   final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
static SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
 public static  String controller_sim ="" ; 
   public static  String master_sim =""; 
   public static  boolean  pass= true;

  public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    controller_sim = sp.getString("controller", "");

    Thread myThread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                // splash screen will show for 6 seconds
                sleep(6000);
                finish();
                if (controller_sim !="")
                {
                 Intent main = new Intent(MainActivity.this, menu.class);
                 startActivity(main);
                  finish();
                  Log.v("main", "perference not present");
                }else{
                      Intent main = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Unitno.class);
                      startActivity(main);
                      finish();
                      Log.v("main", "perference not present");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    myThread.start();


  }
```

}

next activity for saving controller_sim,master_sim

public class Unitno  extends Activity{

```
String unit,master;
EditText controllernumber,masternumber;
Button enter2;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.unitno);
       controllernumber=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textboxcontroller);
       masternumber=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textboxmaster);

        enter2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ent2);
        unit=controllernumber.getText().toString();
        master=masternumber.getText().toString();
        enter2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                        public void onClick(View v) {


                        /*  if(unit.length()<9 && master.length()<9)
                            {
                                controllernumber.setText("");
                                masternumber.setText("");
                                Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter Valid Number",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                  msg.show();
                            }
                           else
                           {
                              /* SharedPreferences store=getSharedPreferences( PREFS_NAME,0);
                               Editor editor = store.edit();
                                 editor.putString("key", unit);
                                 editor.commit();
                                 Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "NO Stored Sucessfully",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                      msg.show();
                                      Intent a=new Intent(Unitno.this,menu.class);
                                      startActivity(a);
                                      finish();*/
                               SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                            Editor editor = sp.edit();
                            editor.putString("controller_sim",unit);
                            editor.putString("master_sim", master);
                            editor.commit();
                            Log.v("ok", unit);
                            Log.v("ok", master);


                          // }
                        }
                        });
 }
```

}

if values are present redirect to this activity

public class menu  extends Activity{

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
     SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPREFERENCES", 0);
        String value = preferences.getString("controller_sim",null);
        if (value == null) {
             Intent main = new Intent(menu.this, Unitno.class);
        } else {
        //
        }
//  SharedPreferences mobno=getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
    // Reading from SharedPreferences
//    String value = mobno.getString("key", "");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
           case R.id.users:
               Intent a=new Intent(menu.this,Users.class);
                  startActivity(a);
               Log.v("User", "You pressed user option!");
                 break;
           case R.id.settings:
               Intent b=new Intent(menu.this,Settings.class);
               startActivity(b);
               Log.v("settings", "You pressed settings option!");
           break;  
           case R.id.help:
               Intent c=new Intent(menu.this,Help.class);
               startActivity(c);
               Log.v("help", "You pressed help option!");
           break;
           case R.id.about:
               Intent d=new Intent(menu.this,Aboutus.class);
               startActivity(d);
               Log.v("Aboutus", "You pressed about option!");
           break;
           case R.id.exit:
               moveTaskToBack(true); 
                menu.this.finish();
               Log.v("ttt", "You pressed the icon!");
           break;

       }
       return true;
   }
```

}

Comment: you are getting value from shared preference in splash screen class, which may be the first class to invoke. then from where are you getting this value.

Comment: i want to make my unit class to invoke when i first install the app after splash screen bcoz the values are null...........and when i set the values it will invoke my menu class after splash screen............

Comment: You want to do something like this.....if blank go to login page otherwise directly at homepage.     Is it

Comment: yes @Barun exactly u got it but i am checking my values during my Splash screen activity plz help me out of this..................urgently

Comment: Also why are you using finish() below sleep line

Comment: @barun can u do some changes if i mail may code to u........plz

Comment: You can talk on my hangout. Kumarbarun42@gmail.com. I will help u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int static FLAG = 0;
FLAG = // get value from shared preference
if(FLAG == 0) {
 //Login Page
}else {
  //home page
}
```

Here initially you will get i=0, and its move to login page, Now enter through login into app. At home page:

```
SplashPage.FLAG = 1;
```

// put the flag in shared preference here.